# Unable to add form in content section magento admin custom extension

Tags: adminhtml, adminform

I am working on magento admin. Try to adding grid with add edit action. But I am stuck at strange issue my form is display in left sidebar under selected tab. Don't know why this happen. Please help me if you know why this is happen[image]

Code of XXXX/XXX/Block/Adminhtml/Dragon/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php

class XXXX_XXX_Block_Adminhtml_Dragon_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                      'form_id' => 'edit_form',
                                      'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('form_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_id'))),
                                      'method' => 'post',
                                      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                   )
      );

      $form->setUseContainer(true);
      $this->setForm($form);
      $this->setTemplate('XXXX/form.phtml');
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your extension you should have this file:

`[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/[Entity]/Edit/Form.php` or something similar. This is the form container class.

Inside that file you should have a method `_prepareForm` that should look like this:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Make sure that the `id` you pass to the `Varien_Data_Form` constructor is `edit_form`.
Use the cms page module as an example: (`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Form`).

Comment: yes i have same code in this file

Comment: @VikrantRoy. I see that you set a custom template to the form `$this->setTemplate('XXXX/form.phtml');`. Try removing that and see what happens. If you have some code in `form.phtml` that you absolutely need you might want to post the contents of that file in the question also.

Comment: i have tried this but still same output

Comment: it has been fixed i was set wrong key element `form_id` instead of `id` thanks @Marius